# Access 2010 How to make Add Record button insert records

Tags: ms-access-2010

I created a combo box field on the form. This combo box field gets the values from a SELECT query. Then I added Add Record button. When this button clicked I want to insert the record in a table. When I click on Add Record button, it doesn't insert record. I'm assuming because it doesn't know in which table to insert the record. How do I make Add Record button insert record in a table.

Joe

Comment: Add *Add Record* button click handler's code into your question. If it's not enough, create ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The Add Record button shows me no code. I'm newbie when it comes to Access.

Comment: Check ["Add Record Button"](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=202889) discussion. There is some steps you should do in your form's **Design View** to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably used *"Button creation assistant"* from Access. It only makes you jump to the data entry form but it does not execute any SQL query.

If so, then you must first **press the "Add record" button** and **then select the value** you want to add in your combobox.

Be sure that your form is bound to the right table (`ControlSource` property). Then link your combobox to the field you are needing to and it should work.